# Creating Data visualisation and a Software toolkit

Tags: java, r, data-visualization

Is it possible to create Data visualisation in R and a app in Java and integrate both into one? if not what are the alterneatives..
I would like my app to be able to download the data visualisations i have created in R.

Comment: Java is a general-purpose language. With enough time and dedication, everything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative : Use Shiny package. Create a webpage from Shiny, use ggplot2 to create data visulaizations and add a download button.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that. But im a computer science student and was looking to complicate it a bit by having some sort of coding. Shiny is just a package that pretty much does everything for you. No coding needed.

Comment: @R07 Not true... a good bit of code is required. Have you actually attempted to build a shiny app?

Comment: @JosephWood No i havent yet. This is my first time attempting R and creating data visualisations.

Comment: @R07, that's okay... Just throwing it out there, it's probably not a good idea to make blanket statements that trivialize something that many people have worked very hard on, especially when you don't know anything about it. Anywho, here is an awesome place to start if you decide to go the Shiny way [Shiny Tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). I hope you take this as a kind word.